# Cloudformation script generates "No subnets found for the default VPC"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have seem the following error during stack creation in number of AWS provided Cloud formation script. Any idea why its generating VPC error?

Error message:
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  WindowsServer   No subnets found for the default VPC 'vpc-aaaaaaa'. Please specify a subnet.

Here is the template:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Roles_And_Features.template

Comment: The template doesnt have the option to allow me to specify a subnet.
I do have subnets created for my VPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template works correctly (I just tried it in my account, in the Sydney region).

It would appear that **the problem lies in your Default VPC**, which is created when your AWS account is setup. It has a CIDR range of `172.31.0.0/16` and should have one Public Subnet in each of your Availability Zones.

Go to the VPC Management Console, go to the **Subnets** view, then change the "Filter by VPC" selector in the top-left to the Default VPC (normally un-named, so choose it via CIDR range). Make sure that you have a subnet in each Availability Zone.

If they are missing, you can create them. Make sure you turn on **Modify Auto-Assign Public IP**. Alternatively, contact AWS Support and ask them to fix/recreate your Default VPC.

Comment: Hi John, I am getting another error message CREATE_FAILED  AWS::EC2::Instance  WindowsServer  The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.  Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Please start a new Question to assist other people in finding answers too. BTW, I did a search on that error message and some people suggest it's related to the instance type or subnet.

Comment: Thanks John, looks like the script only works in Sydney region, not sure why.....

Comment: The script also worked for me in Singapore and US-East. Your issue might be EC2-VPC vs EC2-Classic. In your EC2 Dashboard, in the top-right, see what is displayed. Sydney has only EC2-VPC. However, that would have affected me too, but it was OK.

Comment: we remove the default VPC in all regions and replace with our own configured with TGW. how can we move past this without recreating the default VPC?

Comment: it might be that I missed a VPC property in CloudFormation template and it is falling back to the default VPC thus failing

Comment: @Dennis If this is still a problem, please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment in an old question.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem and the below steps helped me.

1. Deleted the subnet of the vcp the error was referring to
2. Used this command on my shell to create a default subnet

   aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-east-2a

For details please visit this documentation page by [Amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html)

Comment: Had the issue with my account and was not able to create either CF stack as well as EB env as well. This really helped to create my default VPC and subnet and now everything is working fine.

Comment: I am really happy to help. Apologies for replying late.

Answer (score 0):

For my project, I had to create a `AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup` and add `DBSubnetGroupName` to my `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resource to reference it.